# Using setInterval with countUp.js

Tags: jquery, setinterval

How do I get the countup animation to repeat after every 60 seconds. I'm using `countUp.js` for the effect. Tried this;

```
<script>
var options = {
  useEasing : true, 
  useGrouping : true, 
  separator : ',', 
  decimal : '.2', 
  prefix : '', 
  suffix : '' 
};
var ignite = new CountUp("sales", 0, 332.83, 1, 15, options);

setInterval(ignite.start(), 60*1000);

</script>
```

Comment: Can you put that in a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see this code working in this fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/z60sxotr/1/):

```
var options = {
  useEasing : true, 
  useGrouping : true, 
  separator : ',', 
  decimal : '.2', 
  prefix : '', 
  suffix : '' 
};
var ignite = new CountUp("sales", 0, 332.83, 1, 2, options);
ignite.start();

setInterval(function(){
ignite.reset();
ignite.start()

},60 * 1000);
```